# How to add dynamically created hyperlink to stack panel programmatically wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

i am creating hyperlinks and want to add it to stack panel.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= links.Length; i++)
{
    Hyperlink hyperlink = new Hyperlink()
    {
        NavigateUri = new Uri(links[i - 1])
    };
}
hyperlink.RequestNavigate += new System.Windows.Navigation.RequestNavigateEventHandler(this.Hyperlink_RequestNavigate);
mainControl.Children.Add(hyperlink);
```

it gives me error -

> cannot convert to system.windows.documents.hyperlink to system.windows.uielement.

i understand the namespace error but didn't find resolution because in uielement i dint find hyperlink.

Comment: is this winforms or wpf?

Comment: this application is in wpf

Comment: then why in the wide-world-of-sports did you tag winforms?

Answer (score 0):

Use LinkLabel instead of HyperLink

Samples:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class LinkLabelAddLink : Form {
    LinkLabel lnkLA = new LinkLabel();

  public LinkLabelAddLink(){
    Size = new Size(300,250);

    lnkLA.Parent = this;
    lnkLA.Text = "StackOverflow.com";
    lnkLA.Location = new Point(0,25);
    lnkLA.AutoSize = true;
    lnkLA.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    lnkLA.Links.Add(0,7,"www.stackoverflow.com");
    lnkLA.LinkClicked += new System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabelLinkClickedEventHandler(lnkLA_LinkClicked);
  }

  static void Main() 
  {
    Application.Run(new LinkLabelAddLink());
  }
  private void lnkLA_LinkClicked(object sender,LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
  {
      lnkLA.LinkVisited = true;
       System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.Link.LinkData.ToString());
  }
}
```

PS: You need atleast .NET 4.5